# Syntax error while trying to build dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to create a function in python 3 that builds a dataframe from a csv file. However, I keep getting a syntax error when I call

```
y = (data_df["Status"].replace("underperform",0).replace("outperform",1).values.tolist())
```

This line of code is not running, because I never actually call the function. Here is all of my code.

```
def Build_Data_Set(features = ["DE Ratio","Trailing P/E"]):
    data_df = pd.read_csv("key_stats.csv") #created in other file

    X = np.array(data_df[features].values#.tolist())

    y = (data_df["Status"].replace("underperform",0).replace("outperform",1).values.tolist())

    return X,y
```

How should I go about fixing this error?

Comment: Can you post the exact error that you are receiving?

Comment: `X = np.array(data_df[features].values#.tolist())` - You are missing a closing paren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in your `X = np.array(data_df[features].values#.tolist())` - it's there, but it's commented out of the code with the # sign.

Your python interpreter does not know that you actually wanted to end that line there and continues to search for a closing parenthesis. Before it finds one, it stumbles over the assignment in the next line, which is illegal and causes your syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
def Build_Data_Set(features = ["DE Ratio","Trailing P/E"]):
    data_df = pd.read_csv("key_stats.csv") #created in other file

    X = data_df[features].values # already returns an array

    y = data_df["Status"].replace({"underperform": 0, "outperform":1}).values

    return X,y

df = Build_Data_Set()
```